Arabic "Majed" voice randomly not showing in SpeechSynthesis (TTS) API
Browsers with the SpeechSynthesis provide Arabic through one voice "Majed" as ar-001 or ar-SA and it usually works on all browsers except ones that use WebKit I noticed.
On Webkit based browsers, especially iPhones & iPads, that specific voice doesn't appear randomly sometimes! How can I make sure that an Arabic language can always be present/used?
Sample:
Here's a codepen where you can try it yourself. For the SAME device, when I go to that page the first time, Majed appears, but it didn't appear a few times later. You can also just open a developer console on any page and put in window.speechSynthesis.getVoices() and the first element in the list should be arabic (majed)
Screenshots while working & not working:
This is what it looks like on a Mac using Safari sometimes, where Arabic does appear above Daria as it does appear correctly with other browsers and operating systems

This is what it looks like on an iPhone/iPad sometimes, where the Arabic doesn't appear at all when it should appear above "Daria":

Additional Debugging details:
If you put in window.speechSynthesis.getVoices() into the browser console for safari, you usually get 221 voices in the list, and then it show 209 voices when arabic is not visible. And it seems like there's also some Catalan voices that don't appear when Arabic doesn't appear. There were some other issues that were also prevalent only on iOS devices, such as the voices not loading on page load and thus requiring checks until it was loaded

I'm seeing 187 voices in Safari on macOS 13.6.3, and some (including Majed) appear more than once. Keep in mind that the order of voices isn't stable, (chrome sorts by reader name, safari appears to sort by language for most of them but gives up at the end.

@smallpepperz were you able to see Arabic.Majed show up on your iPhone/iPad as well?

yes, I'm seeing Maned on iOS 18.1.1
